# Why is requiredSizeIn not the same as requiredWidthIn + requiredHeightIn with the same parameter values?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

I have the below code

```
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 64.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        item {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(200.dp)
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Green))
            ) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .sizeIn(100.dp, 200.dp)
                    .requiredWidthIn(150.dp, 180.dp)
                    .requiredHeightIn(150.dp, 180.dp)
                    .border(BorderStroke(3.dp, Color.Red))
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

It resulted as expected.

[image]

I just replaced `requiredWidthIn` and `requiredHeigthIn` with `requiredSizeIn` as below.

```
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 64.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        item {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(200.dp)
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Green))
            ) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .sizeIn(100.dp, 200.dp)
                    .requiredSizeIn(150.dp, 180.dp)
                    .border(BorderStroke(3.dp, Color.Red))
                )
            }
        }
```

I expect the result to be the same. Somehow it looks different on the height side. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Different parameters. 
Using named parameters might show which parameter value you are passing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the definitions of each method you are using, you see:

- [`requiredWidthIn(min: Dp, max: Dp)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).requiredWidthIn(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp))
- [`requiredHeightIn(min: Dp, max: Dp)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).requiredHeightIn(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp))
- [`requiredSizeIn(minWidth: Dp, minHeight: Dp, maxWidth: Dp, maxHeight: Dp)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).requiredSizeIn(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp))

So really your second code snippet is saying:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .sizeIn(100.dp, 200.dp)
    .requiredSizeIn(
        minWidth = 150.dp,
        minHeight = 180.dp,
        maxWidth = Dp.Unspecified, // The default
        maxHeight = Dp.Unspecified, // The default
    )
    .border(BorderStroke(3.dp, Color.Red))
)
```

Which is not the same thing - you haven't declared any `maxWidth` or `maxHeight` like you did when using `requiredWidthIn` and `requiredHeightIn`. That's why you are getting a different result - you're setting a `minHeight` of `180.dp` when using `requiredSizeIn` while you're using a `minHeight` of `150.dp` when you are using `requiredHeightIn`.

You'd see the same result if you declare all four parameters to `requiredSizeIn`:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .sizeIn(100.dp, 200.dp)
    .requiredSizeIn(
        minWidth = 150.dp,
        minHeight = 150.dp,
        maxWidth = 180.dp,
        maxHeight = 180.dp
    )
    .border(BorderStroke(3.dp, Color.Red))
)
```

Comment: Nice! How could I miss that!

Comment: I was hoping size simplifies the need to write both width and height. 
If size has additional parameters to do so, and can represent both width and height together, perhaps we can just deprecate width and height.